# Using Zend Mail as a module

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'File "Mail.php" does not exist or class "Mail" was not found in the file' in     C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\Zend\Loader.php:99 

Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\report\bounce.php(9): Zend_Loader::loadClass('Mail') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\Zend\Loader.php on line 99
```

The structure of my folder is:

root/report/call.php
root/pluign/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php

The Zend framework seems have some problem in locating files. How to fix that? thank you

call.php:

```
<?
set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fyp/plugin');
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

//Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

//set_include_path('../plugin/ZendFramework-1.11.11-minimal/library/Zend');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Mail');




$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_IMAP(array('host'     => 'imap.gmail.com',
                                         'user'     => 'admin@gmail.com',
                                         'password' => 'pwd',
                                         'ssl'      => 'SSL',
                                         'port'     => 993
                                         ));




echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";

foreach ($mail as $message) {
    echo "Mail from '{$message->from}': {$message->subject}\n";
}

include("../connection/conn.php");
session_start();

?>
```

Comment: i notice (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR'), is this the reason? why the zend framework will point to that place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the Zend Framework in your php.ini include_path. Which is what `include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR'` is pointing to.
in your php.ini make your include path look something like `include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\path\to\ZendFramework-1.11.11-minimal/library'` then your autoloader should work.

To address your edit:
The class name is not 'Mail'.
`Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Mail');`

With ZF 1.x the classname mimics the path to the file. It's an adhoc namespacing that was done before PHP had namespaces.

so for example `Zend_Mail_Storage_IMAP` would live at `/Zend/Mail/Storage/IMAP`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you . i used set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fyp/plugin');

Comment: would you mind looking at edit version, there are stull some problem

Comment: But the problem is if i use 
set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fyp/plugin');

i don't want to hardcode it since fyp is the folder name subject to change, are there any better way ? thank you

Comment: Since i don't want to change the php.ini

Comment: Last question, can i retrieve the bounce message from gmail using zend? thank you

Comment: as far as i know set_include_path() is likely your best option if you don't want to change your php.ini. As for getting bounced e-mails... I don't know. I've seen the question here several times and I never saw a satisfactory solution.